# display html data depending on wordpress user id

Tags: php, html, wordpress

im working in wordpress. I have 3 users in it, and inside my wordpress dashboard login i have a customized html widget with custom data. This widget has 3 divs

If any of these users log in, can see the 3 divs. But what i want to do is display a specific div for a specific user.

Lets say i have:

```
<div class=“user1”></div>
<div class=“user2”></div>
<div class=“user3”></div>
```

and i want to “user_id=3” only see the next:

```
<div class=“user3”></div>
```

and if user 2 log in, can see the div with class “user2” and hide the others

in wordpress, each user name as for ex: user_id=3

Can anyone who understand php and wordpress help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use PHP to identify the user and then show the appropriate content. This way the page only contains the data the user should see. If you have multiple `<div>` elements then you have to include them all every time. This creates data leaks and security vulnerabilities.

---

**The Problem**


Consider this:
Your page has these `div` elements like you suggested

```
<div class="user1">User1 Information</div>
<div class="user2">User2 Information</div>
<div class="user3">User3 Information</div>
```

When `user1` logs in, you only show the `div` with `class='user1'`. The problem is, that you still include in the page the information for `user2` and `user3`. That's a bad practice, because a skilled user can easily obtain that information by viewing the page's source code.

---

**The Right Way**


You should use the PHP script to identify the user and then print the widget that you want them to see. The code below is a generalized Wordpress script that you will need to adapt to your need.

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = $user->ID;

switch($user_id) {
    case 1: //user1 id
        //show user1 widget
        break;
    case 2: //user2 id
        //show user2 widget
        break;
    case 3: //user3 id
        //show user3 widget
        break;
}
```

Here, you only show the widget that the user should see. This is not the only way to accomplish this and your need with dictate your script. You can use `if` statements or use the `switch` statement or put all the code in a function to contain it all. The solution is up to you, but I hope this gets you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I know the risk and vulnerability but the users are not too skilled and what i do is showing the results from a php function, to read from a .csv file uploaded in the server, so the information is not in the view source. Check this out: http://sebastiangaido.com/sumo/csvdata/ So is possible to show the user a specific div depending o the user?